# Load data in ListBox with check box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I need load some data(Employee) in a listbox with check box. So the problem is how can I load other values, because in this moment only I can load the "Name" of the employee, and I need load other datas like "LastName", "Age", ...etc

I don't know how should be the syntax in the Content.

This is the xaml

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxZone" Content="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding TheValue}" Checked="CheckBoxZone_Checked" 
                  Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to enhance layout of the ListItem template so along with CheckBox you can display another controls:

```
<DataTemplate>  
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition />
       <ColumnDefinition />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Name="CheckBoxZone" Content="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding TheValue}" Checked="CheckBoxZone_Checked" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>     

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

If you want to pass item itself to a content of CheckBox (why you need that?) use simply this:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Name="CheckBoxZone" Content="{Binding}" Tag="{Binding TheValue}" Checked="CheckBoxZone_Checked"   Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, only one questions, how can I get space between the values, for example: "Maikol Smith 36"...

Answer (score 0):

For most flexibility, use a `DataTemplate` for the `CheckBox`.

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding }">
    <CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Family}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Age, StringFormat='({0:d})'}" FontStyle="Italic"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
</CheckBox>
```

[Assuming Age is of type `int`, use `{0:f}` if it's a `double`]

This will result in something like this: Maikol **Smith** *(36)*

Each `Run` tag should be on a new line for the `TextBlock` to insert a space between them.